# NativeScript binding breaks UI

Tags: nativescript

I have setup a custom tab view defined as the following :

> main.xml

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" loaded="loaded" 
xmlns:t1="partial-views/explore"
xmlns:t2="partial-views/community">
<!--ACTION BAR-->
<ActionBar title="Haloose">...</ActionBar>
<StackLayout>
    <!-- TABS -->
    <StackLayout id="sl_main">
        <t1:explore     id="tab_explore"    visibility="{{ currentActive == 'explore' ? 'visible' : 'collapsed' }}" />
        <t2:community   id="tab_community"  visibility="{{ currentActive == 'community' ? 'visible' : 'collapsed' }}"/>
    </StackLayout>
    <-- FIXED MENU -->
    <GridLayout id="menu">
        <Image  tap="changeVisibleTab"/>
        <Image tap="changeVisibleTab" />
    </GridLayout>
</StackLayout>
</Page>
```

Let's call this file `main.xml` . It's associated to a `main.js` where I've defined a binding context:

> main.js

```
exports.loaded = function(args){
    page = args.object;

    //Set Up page view model
    mainObservable = new Observable({
        currentActive:"explore",
        menuItemsArray:[
            new MenuItem("explore"),
            new MenuItem("community")
        ]
    });
    //Bind page to view model
    page.bindingContext = mainObservable;
}
```

For each tab I have a folder containing a `js` , `css` and `xml` file.
A sample `tab.xml` file would look like this :

> tab.xml

```
<StackLayout loaded="tabLoaded" > <looots of stuff /> </StackLayout>
```

**Everything works as expected, however if I try to bind the stack layout to an object , all of the UI elements are hidden.
If I remove binding, I can see them again.**

> not working tab.js

```
var Observable = require("data/observable").Observable;

var profile;
exports.tabLoaded = function(args){
    profile = args.object;
    var profileBinding = {
        username : "Aaron Ullal"
    }
    profile.bindingContext = profileBinding; //removing this line makes elements visible
}
```

What is causing this? Perhaps multi level binding is not supported?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use custom XML components, like your tabs, and add bindings to them (in your case the `visibility` binding, those bindings are basically applied to the root tag in your XML component. So when you change the binding context in your `tab.js` the visibility binding starts looking for a `currentActive` property in `profileBinding`. In order to achieve what you want you have to wrap your tab XML in another layout, like this:

```
<StackLayout>
    <StackLayout loaded="tabLoaded" > 
        <!--looots of stuff --> 
    </StackLayout>
</StackLayout>
```

It should work as expected then.